# What are the G forces the Dragon 2 crew experience during splashdown? And what is the seat angle for the current configuration of 4 astronauts?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, landing, dragon-v2, g-force, crew-size

The Dragon 2 has a crew capacity of seven, but, NASA decided to change the specification for the angle of the ship’s seats due to concerns about the g-forces crew members might experience during splashdown.

So now the capsule can only take four astronauts. Does anyone know what the original angle of the seats was and how much it had to be changed by? And what were the original G-force values and what are the new ones?

Comment: Would the seat configuration change the g-forces produced by external factors unrelated to the seats? I want to guess the new configuration merely puts the astronauts in a better position to withstand the same g-forces as before—I believe I’ve read that our ability to survive high g-forces depends closely on the relative direction of those g-forces (whether they come from the side/top/back...)